# Checking data "exists" in array?

Tags: javascript

I have an small array of data which i want to check if my values im checking against exist in the array together.

This is how the data looks like from my console.log(astar);

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRKlU.jpg

My attempt was:

```
 console.log(astar); // display array info
     for (i=0; i < 50; i++){    
        for (j=0; j < 50; j++){ 
        if( i in astar && j in astar[i] ){
               abposx = getx(i);
               abposy = gety(j);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
        ctx.fillRect (abposx,abposy,10,10);             
    }
```

The idea is the "inner arrays" which have [0][1] positions im trying to see if "any" of them have [0] == i and [1] == j if so = true.

How should i alter it to work correctly & most efficiently - so that it will draw when it is found in the arrays

Comment: What do you mean with "exist in the array together"?

Comment: So basically checking if one of the inner arrays has [0]==i && [1] == j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are currently doing is equivalent to

```
for (i=0; i < astar.length; i++)
    for (j=0; j < astar[i].length; j++) {
        abposx = getx(i);
        abposy = gety(j);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
        ctx.fillRect(abposx,abposy,10,10);
    }
```

You may want:

```
for (i=0; i < astar.length; i++) {
    if (astar[i][0] > 50 || astar[i][1] > 50)
        continue;
    abposx = getx(astar[i][0]);
    abposy = gety(astar[i][1]);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fillRect(abposx,abposy,10,10);
}
```

Looping through all coordinates is very inefficient and would need a third loop for searching in astar. Better loop through astar and paint what you can get.

The correct three-loop code would have been:

```
for (i=0; i < 50; i++)
    for (j=0; j < 50; j++)
        if (astar.some(function(item) {
            return item[0] == i && item[1] == j;
        }) {
            abposx = getx(i);
            abposy = gety(j);
            ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
            ctx.fillRect(abposx,abposy,10,10);
        }
```

(The [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) loops through the array and returns true if an item matches the condition function. It equals the [extended version posted by bfavaretto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10219818/1048572)). Resulting in a performance of O(n^2.5)...

Comment: yes but thats mainly my poor attempt :P im trying to see if the inner arrays have matching values [0][1] to i & j.

Comment: the loop index matching to the values in the astar array?

Comment: well if you see the image i posted - notice the first inner array has [0]=10[1]=10
so then in my loop im checking if that exists such a combination exists any of those arrays and if so it equals true and thus draw.

Comment: Not sure - its missing a closed bracket where would i put it to ?

Comment: @Dave, Just add `}}` at the end, and it should get rid of the syntax error. Bergi, +1 for `some()`!

Comment: @Dave: Thanks, I've deleted the superfluos brackets.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you want to compare with the array values. What you have is an array containing other arrays, each one with only two items inside. You can loop it like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<astar.length; i++) {
    console.log("Array " + i + " contains values " + astar[i][0] + " and " + astar[i][1]);
}
```

**UPDATE**

I'm still not sure I get it, but you may be looking for this:

```
for (i=0; i < 50; i++){    
    for (j=0; j < 50; j++){ 
         for(var k=0; k<astar.length; k++) {
              if(astar[k][0] == i && astar[k][1] == j) {
                    abposx = getx(i);
                    abposy = gety(j);
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
                    ctx.fillRect (abposx,abposy,10,10);
                }
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Im basically checking if the second level arrays which have [0][1] positions have values matching my i and j in the loops.

Comment: Yes, I also think that's what he's looking for. But you forgot to mention NOT to use this "solution" :-)